# Hazelcast Imap.values(Predicate) miss data

Tags: hazelcast-imap

I am using hazelcast3.3.3 for cache.When I use IMap.values(Predicate) querying data,I find a problem.When I use this query,I can find the data.The query is
[image]

the data is
[image]

but when I use this query,I can't find the data.I can make sure the nextExecuteTime is also meet the conditions.Is it a bug of hazelcast?Do you meet such environment?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should work both ways. Could you try:

`Predicates.and(
Predicates.lessThan("nextExecuteTime", 1463975296703),    Predicates.regex("autoIncrementId", ".*[5,6,7,8,9]$")
)`